# How can a Msys2/ucrt64-console be started with parameters for mintty?

Tags: msys2, mintty

C:\msys64\ucrt64.exe

- provides console, but does not accept mintty-parameters eg "-p 0,0".

C:\msys64\usr\bin\mintty.exe -p 0,0

- position is Ok, but the PATH is not correct PATH.
- How could the correct path be set ?
- would it make much easier to start my 8 consoles.